# Why might Location Allocation give long paths when much shorter paths exist?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, shortest-path, location-allocation

I'm using [location-allocation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/location-allocation.htm#GUID-2C5A2A41-83CF-45EC-9D7E-93BF9C417ABC) in the network analyst toolbox of ArcMap to add features to my map.

My objective function is to minimize impedance (meters).
The image below shows the result.

As you can see, there are lines in the top-right that do not go to the closest node pictured. Instead, they go off to a far-away node in the bottom left.

Also, if I increase the number of locations for my solver, this problem occurs for the added locations too. That is, **any locations that I add have points of demand near them who do no go to them**; Instead demands near new locations go to far-away locations.

I'm using a network dataset with junctions set at line intersections. Visually, the component shown below is connected to the rest of the network. 
I double-checked that I'm reading the correct length attribute in my network dataset as well.

The only thing I can think of is that maybe this component below is somehow disconnected.

What could be going on here?

[image: Location Allocation is using giving paths that are too long.]

Comment: I would test the connectivity in route solver then that would be an initial steer.

Comment: Maybe the blue dot has reached its capacity, preventing nearby high-demand points to be allocated to it.  "Excess demand won't be allocated to a facility even if that demand is within the facility's impedance cutoff."